# Graph creation via Neo4j takes too long

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and Python and trying to populate a test database with nodes and relationships using IPython. I am using py2neo v 3.1.2. The problem I am trying to address is representing a collection of sentences in a graph with the sentence id connected to contained words via links having the word count as property.

I have added the relevant Neo4j constraints for both String (num) and Word (val). The relevant code is given here:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Path
import re
graph = Graph("http://neo4j:xxxx@localhost:7474/db/data/")    
f1 = open("test.txt", "r")
cnt = 0
for line in f1:
    cnt = cnt+1
    line=line.lower()
    line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',line)
    wordlist = line.split()
    lgth = len(wordlist)
    wordfreq = [wordlist.count(w) for w in wordlist]
    dct = dict(zip(wordlist,wordfreq))
    str = Node("String", num=cnt, length = lgth)
    graph.merge(str)
    for k, v in dct.items():
        wrd = Node("Word", val=k)
        graph.merge(wrd)
        property_dict = {"wrdcnt": v}
        relate = Path(str, ("CONTAINS",property_dict),wrd)
        graph.merge(relate)
```

---

A small collection of 1000 lines takes around 10 minutes to populate as a graph in Neo4j. I am sure that I am doing something incorrectly in my python code and the same can be sped up significantly. Would appreciate any meaningful insights..

Comment: Have you benchmarked just your parsing? Also: You're performing a significant amount of merges. Perhaps edit your question to show the core Cypher queries you'd be running, on import.

Comment: I benchmarked the parsing..the python code zips through sub-second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running 2 queries *per word* in each sentence, plus another query per sentence; it's taking a long time because you are incurring a massive amount of overhead by using those `py2neo` convenience methods. You can cut way back to a single query per sentence if you use parameters and put more of the work onto Cypher:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import maketrans, punctuation
no_punc = maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for ct, line in enumerate(f1):
        line = line.lower().translate(no_punc).split()
        length = len(line)
        dct = Counter(line)
        graph.run('''
            MERGE (s:Sentence { id:{count}, length: {s_length} })
            WITH s
            UNWIND keys({dct}) AS word
            MERGE (w:Word { id: word })
            MERGE (s) - [:CONTAINS {wrdcnt: {dct}[word] }] -> (w)''',
            parameters={'dct': dct, 's_length': length, 'count': ct})
```

RABBITHOLE: This is the entire thing performed in one query. It is not pretty, but it's potentially the fastest. Also, make sure you have indexes on `:Sentence(id)` and `:Word(id)` in either case, it will speed up both dramatically.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import maketrans, punctuation
no_punc = maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))
params = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for ct, line in enumerate(f1):
        line = line.lower().translate(no_punc).split()
        length = len(line)
        dct = Counter(line)
        params.append({'dct': dct, 's_length': length, 'count': ct})
graph.run('''
    UNWIND {params} AS param
    WITH param['dct'] AS dct, param['count'] AS ct, param['s_length'] AS s_length
    MERGE (s:Sentence { id: ct, length: s_length })
    WITH s, dct
    UNWIND keys(dct) AS word
    MERGE (w:Word { id: word })
    MERGE (s) - [:CONTAINS {wrdcnt: dct[word] }] -> (w)''',
    parameters={'params': params})
```

Comment: The following error is thrown up in IPython - CypherSyntaxError: WITH is required between MERGE and UNWIND

Comment: yeah, that one catches me every time. It's fixed above.

Comment: Thanks, this has sped up the program..it now takes sub-2 minutes for 1000 lines (6334 nodes, 21777 relations). But wondering if this can be improved upon. Earlier, I have tried importing csv formats with half-million nodes in under 5 minutes. However, the current task is text-oriented

Comment: The CSV import allows streaming and performs all of its parsing inside Cypher, and is extremely fast as a result. You can fit all of this into one query statement, but it won't be pretty... see above.

Comment: Great..zips through in seconds. Thanks, again

Comment: yeah, there is definitely an upper limit on how far you can stretch this. Single queries are much faster, but the entire query has to sit in heap before the transaction can close. Find a reasonable page size and iterate the query over those pages using `itertools.islice` or similar.